# Highcharts, trying to regulate maximum height of chart columns NOT including Axes

Tags: graph, highcharts, bar-chart, calculated-columns

I have this Highcharts chart but depending on the Height the bars are spilling over into the Axes. I set the height of the chart to 150, but this includes a number of other things other than just the chart's columns, like the axes and whatnot.  Is there any way to say, "Set the column with the maximum value to 'x' pixels, no matter what the maximum value is". Much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but you can play around with `minPadding` and `maxPadding`. If you have fixed height of the chart (always the same) then you can set that values.

See references:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minPadding
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding